# Is it possible to have light without heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, visible-light

I am trying to think of a light source that doesn't generate heat; but I am not sure if such a phenomenon exists.

I am not referring to passive light (such as reflected light, ie, moonlight) but an active light *source* that does not have heat as a by-product.

Is it possible to generate light without *heat*, or put it a bit differently, without *burning something*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a phenomenon that generates light without generating heat as by-product*. The phenomenom is called [Electroluminescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroluminescence), and is used in [LEDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode) which are used in many electric equipment (the tiny lights in your computer to let you know it's on).

We can stretch it a bit more with [Fluorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence) and other forms of creating [liminous paint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminous_paint)

Also if you will, we can consider [Annihilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation), which will only generate light

- Please be aware that you will always generate heat in real systems, because you can never have the idealized phenomenom, for example in LEDs, you will have a tiny amount of heat generated due to the inherent resitence in the LED though the passing current, but the phenomenom itself only generates light

Comment: I think I need to explain a bit more - is there a specific property of light that needs heat? (not sure if this makes sense) - in other words, could we have a light that doesn't require heat? By light I mean observable light, not some odd wavelength.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Maybe you mean to say, is it possible for matter to be at absolute zero and emit photons?

Comment: Let us not forget the humble fire-fly and chemiluminescence.